# Is my definition of the LISP cons-cell list correct?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to really understand LISP in order to have a good foundation moving forward, but it's been slow going because LISP (specifically Common Lisp in my case) doesn't follow any C family naming conventions.

Here's my personal definition of a LISP list, is it *basically* correct?:
All lists in LISP are constructed as singly linked lists using void pointers for both the node and next pointer.

Edit: for clarification, I'm using the words 'void pointer' to indicate an idea about the nature the cons-cell's CAR and CDR. I understand that 'void pointer' doesn't exist in LISP, I'm trying to apply *concepts* from C to LISP here

Comment: " is it basically correct?:" - no, why would you use void pointers? And why would they have to be implemented in C or C++?

Comment: I'm trying to apply my understand of computing from the C family of languages to a foreign body of understanding, in this case Lisp. What's important is not the name 'void pointer' in the LISP context but that 'void pointer' means a typeless pointer to my brain. I'm asking if that understanding is correct

Comment: LISP does not follow C conventions because it is a decade older... Better don't try to map LISP concepts to C, because they are very different languages...

Comment: C doesn't have any convention for linked lists. There is no linked list in the standard C library. Every programmer chooses their own name for a linked list node, and its representation: is it doubly linked, singly linked; does it contain the data or point to it, and so on.  C programs which implement Lisp dialects often use the Lisp terminology, like `struct cons { value *car, *cdr; }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic Lisp data structures, expressed in C language terms, *might* look like this:

```c
/* A value is a "discriminated union". */
typedef struct value {
  /* It has a type field. */
  enum type { t_cons, t_symbol, t_fixnum, t_character /* , ... */ } type;

  /* And then one of several payloads, overlaid in the same space,
     which one being there depending on the type field. */
  union {
    struct symbol *sym;
    struct cons *cons;
    int fixnum;   /* unboxed integer: no heap allocation */
    /* ... */
  } u;
} value;

/* This is the heap-allocated part of a cons cell;
   not the complete cons cell value, which is actually
   of "struct value" type. See cons()
   function below which makes a cons value. */
struct cons {
  struct value car, cdr;
};

static  value nil = { t_symbol };

value cons(value a, value d)
{
   value retv;
   struct cons *c = allocate_cons(); /* from special cons heap */
   c->car = a;
   c->cdr = c;
   retv.type = t_cons;
   retv.u.cons = c;
   return retv;
}

int is_nil(value v)
{
  return (v.type == t_symbol && v.sym == NULL);
}

value cons(value a, value d)
{
   struct value retv;
   struct cons *c = allocate_cons(); /* from special cons heap */
   c->car = a;
   c->cdr = c;
   retv.type = t_cons;
   retv.u.cons = c;
   return retv;
}

value car(value arg)
{
  switch (arg.type) {
  case t_cons:
    return arg.u.cons->car;
  case t_symbol:
    if (is_nil(arg))   /* (car nil) -> nil */
      return nil;
    /* fallthrough */
  default:
    /* This function generates a Lisp exception somehow */
    throw_error("car: not applicable to ~s", arg);
  }
}
```

The Lisp concept doesn't specify the data structuring down to this detail.

Actual Lisp implementations usually do something more clever for a more compact representation of `value`. A common technique is to use a machine word (often pointer-sized nowadays) for a Lisp value, and to use several *tag bits* within that word which indicate whether it is pointer to something on the heap, or a direct representation of an integer. (This means that the Lisp `fixnum` integer doesn't use all 32 or 64 bits that are available, but perhaps only 30 or 62. Larger integers are of a different type `bignum`, and are heap-allocated.)

Using structures for values rather than pointers, however, creates the opportunity for *by value* semantics for floating-point values, which is a win for numeric code. Meaning that floating-point objects don't have to be heap allocated but stored within a value.

Lisp implementation written in C can do this sort of trickery, but it results in ISO C undefined behavior, and declarations and code aren't as nice for illustrative purposes.

With this type of representation, a nice detail is to use a C null pointer for the Lisp symbol `nil`.  Then any internal routines written in C can be ergonomically written using the same conventions as Lisp: that `nil` is both false and the empty list.

C is quite influenced by Lisp in that it is based on expressions which return values, and that null pointers are false. The `a?b:c` ternary operator in C is somewhat of a knockoff of Lisp's `(if a b c)`.

It takes quite a lot of lines of code of C to bootstrap something which looks like Lisp-like semantics, and there are multiple design choices for numerous aspects of it. Therefore, it is better to try to understand Lisp as an abstraction, and not through a particular detailed data structure and execution model design, let alone one expressed in C.

Answer (score 2):

The Common Lisp HyperSpec is the standard and it describes the behaviour of the forms and functions and perhaps some requirements on complexity, but it **never** interferes with how the low level implementation of data structure is done. You may implement CL in a language that does not expose any hardware or you can do it C using void* pointers as values.

In many implementations though a value is a pointer in the machine and thus void* describes it perfectly. Cons is an array of two machine words and `car` and `cdr` can have any value in it. Thus it isn't simply a mere linked list unless you restrict it to be in your use. You can make a tree structure or model any kind og data structure with this.

Since all pointers are indexes to bytes and a word usually are 4 or 8 bytes each pointer will have either 2 or 3 bits always zero. Many implementations cleverly adds information in these bits in order to tell what the pointer represents. Eg. if the lsb is 1 one might interpret the address as a fixed signed integer and you get it's real value by shifting it right 1 bit with carry. A cons cell might have all the tag bits set to `2`. This is the reason two fixnums can be `eq`.

Now a proper list `(1 2 3)` is read in and printed like that, but if you read `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` you get the same output. The illusion of a list using `cons` is embedded in the `read` and `write` functions so that it just works when the `cdr` has the right type. A cons can have any values but will then be shown in dotted representation if the `cdr` is anything other thn `cons` or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of a Lisp list as a CONS pair that has value in the CAR and a list in the CDR or nil (empty list). You can think of any list as their structural CONSes.

e.g. `(list 1 2 3)` => `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there's an explanation that will fit your view in the new data structures page on the [Common Lisp Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html).

(in short, I'm no pro, but I tend to agree with your definition: a list is a continuation of cons cells that finish with a null pointer).

The list basic element is the cons cell. We build lists by assembling
cons cells.

```
(cons 1 2)
;; => (1 . 2) ;; representation with a point, a dotted pair.
```

It looks like this:

```
[o|o]--- 2
 |
 1
```

If the `cdr` (the `rest`) of the first cell is another cons cell, and if the `cdr` of
this last one is `nil`, we build a list:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))
;; => (1 2)
```

It looks like this:

```
[o|o]---[o|/]
 |       |
 1       2
```

(ascii art by [draw-cons-tree](https://github.com/cbaggers/draw-cons-tree)).

See that the representation is not a dotted pair ? The Lisp printer
understands the convention.

Finally we can simply build a literal list with `list`:

```
(list 1 2)
;; => (1 2)
```

or by calling quote:

```
'(1 2)
;; => (1 2)
```

which is shorthand notation for the special form `(quote (1 2))`.